# Function to load datatable after calling ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

This is my first time using Jquery and Ajax so im very new to this. I wrote a Jquery function that grabs the data from the user and sends it to Actionresult when the action result runs a lot of linq queries and returns the Data back to to the success area (data). Where I am having trouble is I need to write a function that grabs (data) and loads it into a data table. I am not sure what that would look like. I was hoping someone could help me on how to call the data after it reaches success. I also get an error by the (indata){ under the bracket  the error says to add a } but I already did.

```
<script>

var ttpath = "../Scripts/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf";
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        //var sheet = $('#SheetName').serialize();
        //var filepath = $('#FileUpload').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            "url": '@Url.Action("GetAttData", "Admin")',
            "data": formData,
            "type": 'POST',
            xhr: function() { 
                var myxhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myxhr.upload){

                }
                return myxhr;
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            'success': function (data) {
                alert("success")
                loadDataTables(data);
            },
            'error': function () {
                alert("failed")
            },

            function:loadDataTables (inData){

            $('#tstarTable').DataTable({
                "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "tableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": ttpath
                },
                ajax: {                
                    "type": 'GET',
                },

                columns: [
                    {
                        title: "ATT IP",
                        data: "ATTIP"
                    },


                    {
                        title: "ICCID",
                        data: "ATTICCID"
                    },


                    {
                        title: "STATUS",
                        data: "ATTSTATUS"

                    },

                    {
                        title: "Session",
                        data: "ATTSession"
                    },

                    {
                        title: "Activated",
                        data: "ATTActivated"
                    },

                    {
                        title: "Trackstar IP",
                        data: "IP"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Vehicle Name",
                        data: "VehicleName"
                    },

                    {
                        title: "Vehicle Group",
                        data: "VehicleGroupName"
                    },

                    {
                        title: "Phone Number",
                        data: "PhoneNumber"
                    },

                    {
                        title: "M5 Match",
                        data: "Unit_No"
                    },

                     {
                         title: "Using Depart",
                         data: "Using_Dept"
                     },

                      {
                          title: "Using Dept Desc",
                          data: "Using_Dept_Desc"
                      },

                       {
                           title: "Status",
                           data: "Status"
                       },

                        {
                            title: "Change Date",
                            data: "Change_DT"
                        }
                ]
            });

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Pull your loadDataTables function outside of the AJAX call.

Comment: Why don't you have datatables initialise the table using ajax? https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Answer (score 0):

There were some errors in your code, it should be structured as follows:

```
var ttpath = "../Scripts/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf";
$(function () {

   function loadDataTables (inData){             
      $('#tstarTable').DataTable({
         "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
         "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": ttpath
         },
         ajax: {                
            "type": 'GET'
         },          
         columns: [
            {
               title: "ATT IP",
               data: "ATTIP"
            },
            {
               title: "ICCID",
               data: "ATTICCID"
            },
            {
               title: "STATUS",
               data: "ATTSTATUS"
            },
            {
               title: "Session",
               data: "ATTSession"
            },
            {
               title: "Activated",
               data: "ATTActivated"
            },
            {
               title: "Trackstar IP",
               data: "IP"
            },
            {
               title: "Vehicle Name",
               data: "VehicleName"
            },
            {
               title: "Vehicle Group",
               data: "VehicleGroupName"
            },
            {
               title: "Phone Number",
               data: "PhoneNumber"
            },
            {
               title: "M5 Match",
               data: "Unit_No"
            },
            {
               title: "Using Depart",
               data: "Using_Dept"
            },
            {
               title: "Using Dept Desc",
               data: "Using_Dept_Desc"
            },
            {
               title: "Status",
               data: "Status"
            },
            {
               title: "Change Date",
               data: "Change_DT"
            }
         ]
      });
   }

   $("form").submit(function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();

       var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
       //var sheet = $('#SheetName').serialize();
       //var filepath = $('#FileUpload').serialize();

       $.ajax({
           "url": '@Url.Action("GetAttData", "Admin")',
           "data": formData,
           "type": 'POST',
           xhr: function() { 
               var myxhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
               if(myxhr.upload){

               }
               return myxhr;
           },
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           'success': function (data) {
               alert("success")
               loadDataTables(data);
           },
           'error': function () {
               alert("failed")
           }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: yes thank you. You are correct I fix the part with the error after he said pull the function out. I have it flipped around does that matter

Comment: @AMore, I corrected some other missing closing brackets besides pulling the function out and correcting it's syntax.

Comment: I understand I did that as well im still not pulling in the data correctly into the datatable. It is json data